# python & maven (unit test integration)

Tags: python, unit-testing, maven

I have a project that mainly Java (using maven as the build tool) and we are looking to add some python modules.  It's easy enough to place the code in src/main/python but I haven't found a nice way to integrate maven's test framework to our python unit tests.  Is there a nice way to get it so that my java unit tests and python unit tests are run with the same maven goal?  (Bonus points if the results of the python unit tests will show up in the site reports).

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be what you're looking for.  There are a few other places where this is discussed.

http://steveberczuk.blogspot.com/2009/12/continuous-integration-of-python-code.html

http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Comment: I've tried playing around with the exec plugin similar to above, but I couldn't get the "result" of the unit test to propagate into maven.  For example, we use Hudson for continuous integration, and if the python unit test failed, we at a minimum need it to be reflected there.  Was there something I missed for getting maven to look at the return code of the exec process?

Comment: @Mark: "result"?  The status code?  Or the log?  If you want the status code, that's the exist status of the process.  See `successCodes`.  If you want the log, that's what stdout and stderr are for.  See `outputFile`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response: Maybe I'm binding to the wrong lifecycle method, but if the exec process returns an error, won't it stop the build or just silently fail?  For example if a junit test fails, it records the error but continues with the build and tests and I get view the surefire report to see the test details (and Hudson will mark the build as unstable because a test failed but the build succeeded).  A exec wont hook into that system (at least as far I understand it now).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired on http://steveberczuk.blogspot.com/2009/12/continuous-integration-of-python-code.html (as pointed out by @S.Lott), here is a working example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>python-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>python3</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-m</argument>
                            <argument>unittest</argument>
                            <argument>discover</argument>
                            <argument>.</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In this case our tests are on ${project.build.directory} and the build machines has `python3` installed.

Answer (score 0):

The guys at ShiningPanda seems to have done some work on this, their blog post explaining how they do it is at http://www.shiningpanda.com/blog/2012/04/25/python-java-unified-build-process-14/

Answer (score -1):

You might also look into http://mavenjython.sourceforge.net/test/. Still, Jython might not support stuff you use in your Python code.