# success code when executing python unit tests through maven

Tags: python, maven, maven-plugin, python-unittest

I have a mixed java/python project which is built using maven. During the build, all unit tests are run fine, python test failures are reported in the log, but the success code remains "SUCCESS" and is unaffected by failing test cases. [python & maven (unit test integration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881482/python-maven-unit-test-integration) addresses a similar issue and one answer mentions the usage of configuration element "successCode", is anyone familiar with how exactly these should be configured?

My attempt (does not work):

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
       <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>python unittest</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>${python.script}</executable>                      
    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/python/</workingDirectory>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>SessionTestSuite.py</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <successCodes>
                            <successCode>0</successCode>
                            <successCode>1</successCode>
                        </successCodes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, but is it pertinent in any way? Any ideas on how to achive this on a newer version? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the return code the SessionTestSuite.py script in case of test failures...

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise, added successCode = 0 and in the python script SessionTestSuite.py i return as follows: 

    sys.exit(len(result.failures))

where result is an object of unittest.TestResult.

Thanks